# Is it appropriate to conduct a Kruskal-Wallis test with the mean of a 3 item construct measured on a 7-point Likert scale as independent variable?

Tags: group-differences, kruskal-wallis-test

I am working on my master's thesis and conducted two studies. The first study utilizes 3 groups. The problem is, that the group sizes are very small (n1 = 13, n2 = 14, n3 = 14). I want to test if there are significant differences in the independent variable (construct measured with 4 items with a 7-point Likert scale). Do I use the mean of the 4 items for every observation as the input for the independent variable of the Kruskal-Wallis test? I am working with R, so i only have to specify the groups and independent variable to conduct the KW.

Best regards
Tom